# Выбрать повторяющиеся значения на интервалах дат

Tags: sql-server

у меня есть таблица посещений с именем клиента, ID посещения  и датой посещения. Нужно выбрать только те посещения, когда один клиент приходил больше одного раза за 10 дней. Я смогла достать только клиентов, которые приходили более 1 раза вообще за все время, но как сделать проверку дат, и возможно ли это вообще? то есть должен быть цикл дат, чтобы они входили в интервал "начальная дата"; "начальная дата+10" по группам посещений одного клиента.

Что я имею:

```
ID  имя   дата
123 иванов 10.05.19
232 иванов 12.05.19
445 петров 13.05.19
546 иванов 25.05.19
568 петров 10.06.19
```

Что нужно получить

```
123 иванов 10.05.19
232 иванов 12.05.19
```

И как быть, если совпадение должно быть 3 и более? и не только по имени клиента, а еще по одному столбцу. Код такой:

```
with DuplicateValue AS (
        SELECT concat  (BookingUserList ,', ', patientref) as pd1, COUNT(*) AS CNT
       FROM Booking
       GROUP BY BookingUserList, patientref
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 2

  )

  select bookingid,BookingUserList , patientref
  from booking 
  where concat(BookingUserList ,', ', patientref) in (select pd1 from DuplicateValue) 
      order by patientref, BookingUserList
```

Нужно как то добавить интервал дат.

Comment: Какой сервер и его версия?

Comment: server management studio 2012

Comment: Это конечно хорошо что среда в которой вы работает 2012 года, но это далеко не означает что вы используете SQLServer 2012

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM Booking t1, Booking t2
WHERE t1.patientref = t2.patientref
AND t1.BookingDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -10, t2.BookingDate) 
                       AND DATEADD(day,  10, t2.BookingDate)
```

Comment: Красиво, но разве у вас период не 20 дней выходит?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Период 10 дней. Но в каждую сторону...

Comment: `больше одного раза за 10 дней` Условие автора, если я правильно понял подразумевает 10 дней(+/-5), но это не важно, всеравно красивый и простой запрос =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков *10 дней(+/-5)* Это неверно. Если разница составляет 6 или там 8 дней - существует 10-дневный период, который "накрывает" оба посещения. Другой вопрос - правильная интерпретация этих "10 дней". Может иметься в виду "разность не более 10 дней", а может иметься в виду "попадают в один 10-дневный период" (тогда макс. разница - не более 9 дней). Но это уже несложно подкорректировать заменой константы.

Comment: спасибо большое! имеется в виду попадают в один 10ти дневный период. То есть с 01.01 по 10.01, с 02.01 по 11.01, с 03.01 по 12.01 и тд.

Comment: @MashaDeineka *имеется в виду попадают в один 10ти дневный период* Тогда константа в запросе должна быть +/-9.